# WPF listview. How to support simultaneously row background color and alternateIndex for this row

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, triggers

I have a `listview` that contains log messages. I want to set the background color for each row in `listview` according to the severity of its corresponding entry. I do this using `DataTrigger` *(see the example)*.

I would also like to support `AlternationIndex` for `listview`.
How can I combine them in *`xaml DataTrigger abd Trigger`* for background color of row?

For set background color for row I use the following code:

```
<ListView ... >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Severity} Value="Info">

                   <Setter 
                     Property="Background" 
                     Value="{Binding Path=Severity,
                             Converter=
                               {StaticResource msgSeverityToColorConverter}}" 
                   />

                 </DataTrigger>

                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Severity} Value="Error">

                   <Setter 
                     Property="Background" 
                     Value="{Binding Path=Severity, 
                             Converter=
                            {StaticResource msgSeverityToColorConverter}}"
                    />

                 </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListView>
```

And for AlternateIndex I have the following code:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>

     </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">

   <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>

    </Trigger>

 </Style.Triggers>
```

I need that when row with message is not `Info` or `Error`, it will be of color from `AlternationIndex` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all due to order of declarations of triggers. First declare the alternation triggers and then the severity triggers.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Severity} Value="Info">
        <Setter Property="Background" 
                Value="{Binding Path=Severity,
                Converter="{StaticResource msgSeverityToColorConverter}}" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Severity} Value="Error">
        <Setter Property="Background" 
                Value="{Binding Path=Severity, 
                Converter="{StaticResource msgSeverityToColorConverter}}" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```